# Laravel Dusk says Class 'Tests\Browser\Components\...' could not be found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk, laravel-dusk2

After I installed laravel-dusk following the official Laravel documentation and run this command:

```
php artisan make:component CardComponentTest
```

Then try to run immediately:

```
php artisan dusk tests/Browser/Components/CardComponentTest.php
```

I get this error:

```
Class 'Tests\Browser\Components\CardComponentTest' could not be found in '/var/www/html/tests/Browser/Components/CardComponentTest.php'.
```

I tested file and path are correct:

```
ls -l /var/www/html/tests/Browser/Components/CardComponentTest.php
```

And it says:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 djw djw 6917 Dec  3 11:25 /var/www/html/tests/Browser/Components/CardComponentTest.php
```

So it is exists and readable.

I checked the namespace in the file:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser\Components;
```

It also looks good.

I checked the `composer.json` and in this I have this section:

```json
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
```

So the file exists, the namespace is good and the namespace is picked up in the composer.json.

I tried to run `composer dump-autoload` too. All good.

Any ide what's wrong whit this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error:

```
Class 'Tests\Browser\Components\CardComponentTest' could not be found in '/var/www/html/tests/Browser/Components/CardComponentTest.php'.
```

indicate you don't have CardComponentTest test case. Because CardComponentTest is not test case but just an component/part of test.

As aless said, component is not a test itself. But if you really want to test `CardComponentTest` you can replace

```
use Laravel\Dusk\Component as BaseComponent;

class CardComponentTest extends BaseComponent
```

to :

```
use Tests\DuskTestCase;
 
class CardComponentTest extends DuskTestCase
```

after you do that you can run `php artisan dusk tests/Browser/Components/CardComponentTest.php` , You just need to add test method first like. An example:

```
public function testComponentExample()
{
    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
        $browser->visit('/')
                ->assertSee('Laravel');
    });
}
```

But create test case in component folder is not best practice. You should create test case like official documentation said. Run `dusk:make` instead of `dusk:component`. An example:

```
php artisan dusk:make SimpleBrowserTest
```

and now you can run

```
php artisan dusk tests/Browser/SimpleBrowserTest.php
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the documentation, the Component is **not** a test itself. Hence, you should **not** name the component "*Test" and you should not try to run the component like a dusk test.

You will use your component in your dusk test as described here:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/dusk#using-components

Components are for repeated actions, like selecting a date in a picker, which is then further used in your test case for example in a form or maybe some change in your UX happens that is assertable.